# (Priority) How do i use setListAdapter for a specific ListView in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview, android-fragments

I am just programming a data evaluation app for a hydropower station.
There i need to download the data from the server, which ist lying there - as a MySQL table, formatted to a JSON-array.
Now after umpteen hours of work i've done it to connect to the server, download the data and to output it in a auto-generated ListView Layout (with *this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));* )

But this was just a testapplication for the connection.

In the main app i need the dataoutput from the server in a specifiv ListView in one of the Fragments. After again trying around some hours without any success I decided to ask you.
The setListAdapter is not working in a FragmentActivity anymore.

And another question: Is it possible to save those data in specific variables, after downloading it from our server?

Greetings from beatiful Austria,
Duned

```
package at.duned.hydroevaluation;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.List;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Fragment2_DataOutput extends Fragment {

InputStream is;
ArrayList<String> results =new ArrayList<String>();
JSONObject json_data;
TextView tw09;
ListView list;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View V=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2_dataoutput,container, false);

    TextView tw09 = (TextView)V.findViewById(R.id.TextView09);
    ListView list = (ListView)V.findViewById(R.id.list);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    getData();

    //tw09.setText((CharSequence) is);

    return V;
}





private void getData() {

    String result = "";
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


        try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://patrickhartl.lima-city.de/eva1.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Fehler bei der http Verbindung "+e.toString());}




try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "n");
        } 
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());}




try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        results.add((String) json_data.get("Messdaten") + " "+ json_data.get("Wert") + " " + json_data.get("Einheit"));
        } 
        fillList();
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
        }



public void fillList() {
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The setListAdapter is not working in a FragmentActivity anymore

`setListAdapter()` is a method on `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`. You call `setAdapter()` on your `ListView` in other cases, such as this one.

Also, please get rid of your `StrictMode` stuff and fix your app to move your I/O into a background thread.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Could you show me a example or a link to a example or edit my code, cause I have no plan how to your 'setAdapter()' here?
I will remove the 'StrictMode' later, when I have time. I already tried it with 'AsyncTask' without success, I am happy it runs anyway, so now i don't mind about this.